# google.script.run.withSuccessHandler() returns Undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I created an array in a separate GS file using the code provided below. I tried calling it in my HTML file. My goal is to compare the contents the array to the parameter `email`. However, the value returned by `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler()` is `undefined`

```js
//in GS
function mailGetter()
{
  //open sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://sheet.url").getSheetByName("Email Sheet").activate();
  //get size of given row range
  var row_data_email = sheet.getRange("C2:C").getValues();
  var emailArray = row_data_email.join().split(',').filter(Boolean);
  Logger.log(emailArray);
  
  return emailArray;
}
```

```
//in HTML
function checkEmail(email) 
    {
      var reg1 = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
      var arraySize = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(misc).sizeGetter(); 
      console.log(arraySize);
      var emailArray = new Array(arraySize);
      emailArray = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(misc).mailGetter();
      console.log(emailArray);
      
      if (reg1.test(email) == false) 
      {
        emails.style.border = "1px solid red";
        document.getElementById('submitBtn').disabled = true;
      } 
      else if (reg1.test(email) == true) 
      {
        emails.style.border = "1px solid green";
        document.getElementById('submitBtn').disabled = false;
      }
      
      for (var row = 0; row < arraySize; row++)
      {
        if (emailArray[row][0] == email)
        {
          emails.style.border = "1px solid green";
          document.getElementById('submitBtn').disabled = false;
          break;
        }
        else if (emailArray[row][0] != email)
        {
          emails.style.border = "1px solid red";
          document.getElementById('submitBtn').disabled = true;
        }
      }
    }

    function misc()
    {
      console.log("Pass");
    }
```

Comment: Where is function `misc`?

Comment: I forgot to include it since it just writes 'Pass' in the console log. Sorry for that

Comment: function ``misc`` will receive the `arraySize` and ``emailArray``. Client calls the server function `sizeGetter()`> Server takes it's own time > client doesn't wait for server to return and does whatever it does in the mean time > After a while, Server returns the `arraySize`  to client > client receives it in the function passed to successHandler(i.e., the `misc` function). TLDr: Client  asks server to do something and call it back at this number ( the success handler function) after the server finished the work the client asked it to do.

Comment: I just checked using console.log() and the values were actually stored in there. Do I have a way to get the values in `function checkEmail()` instead of `function misc()` ?

Answer (score 6):

#### Issue:

- Using a asynchronous function's(`google.script.run`) return value, which will always be `undefined`.

#### Solution:

- Use successHandler as mentioned in another answer or We can use promises with async/await.

#### Snippet:

```
/*Create a promise around old callback api*/
const p = func => 
  new Promise(resolve=>
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(resolve)[func]()
  );

async function checkEmail(email) //modified
    {
      var arraySize = await p('sizeGetter');//Wait to resolve
      console.log(arraySize);
      //var emailArray = new Array(arraySize);
      var emailArray = await p('mailGetter');//Wait to resolve
      console.log(emailArray);
      //....
    }
```

#### Note:

- It's better to reduce the number of calls to the server. If you can combine both `Getter`s to a single server function, it'll be better.
- The above is a snippet showing how to use `async`/`await`. But if you wait for each response from the server as shown above, your front end/UI will be slow. Wait only if absolutely necessary. Calls to server should be non-blocking/asynchronous.

#### References:

- [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Creating_a_Promise_around_an_old_callback_API)
- [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Answer (score 1):

Issue is in these lines:

```
emailArray = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(misc).mailGetter();
console.log(emailArray);
```

You're  trying to execute `mailGetter()` and expecting it to return value which you're storing in `emailArray` but `this method is asynchronous and does not return directly`

Rather you'll get the value in callback which you have defined as `SuccessHandler`

Suggested solutions :

1. Calling Apps Script functions from a template : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#apps_script_code_in_scriptlets
2. Calling Apps Script APIs directly : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#calling_apps_script_apis_directly
3. Pushing variables to templates : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#pushing_variables_to_templates

Reference : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myFunction(...)

Comment: Are there any ways to bypass this problem? Or do I have to redo my code all over again to fix this?

Comment: You will need to write two functions: one which calls the server, and one which acts as a callback to do the rest of the stuff you're trying to do. You can probably reuse the functioning parts of your current code.

Comment: By calling the server, do you mean a code that has access to the spreadsheet and getting the contents from there?